# Informatica windows job scheduling

Tags: scheduled-tasks, etl, jobs, informatica-powercenter

need help :
informatica is installed on windows ,
so pmcmd will not work to schedule informatica workflow,
n e patch or utility to schedule informatica  workflow (on windows)  through unix(pmcmd).

any other solution to schedule informatica workflow (on windows). ??

Comment: in command promt - no gateway connectivity is provided for domain in informatica

Comment: if you have sample batch script for the same, can you please share.

Answer (score 1):

Please Google for the error you have: " no gateway connectivity is provided for domain". And to resolve the issue, add the environment variable INFA_DOMAINS_FILE.

More can be found for example on: [this page](http://myinformatica.blogspot.com/2008/02/pcsf46007-no-gateway-connectivity-is.html)

Answer (score 0):

We can run pmcmd command from windows command line.In command line mode we have to give every bit of information like (domain name,integration service name,username and passwords in each command.Below is the syntax

pmcmd startworkflow -sv Myintservice -d Mydomain -u username -p password -f foldername workflowname

Please lookup the help of pmcmd command just to make sure if I have misstated anything.